# Search and Replace in a Class file in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, search, replace

How can I perform a simple "search and replace" in Eclipse (for Java), like you do with "Ctr+Shift+H" in Visual Studio?

I want to replace ocurrence by ocurrence, like when you press "Ctr+Shift+H" -> "Find Next" in Visual Studio.

Extra 1: is there a way to search within a specific string in Eclipse?

Extra 2: Is there any way to search within a mouse-selected text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Eclipse you can find and replace occurence by occurence by opening the find/replace assistant (**Menu Edit -> Find/Replace** or **Command+F** on Mac, I guess Control+F on Windows)

Then use ***find*** button  with forward as selected direction for ***Find Next*** and backward as selected direction for ***Find Previous***. Same thing as replace, you'll need to click on ***replace*** button, based on the selected direction, it will replace next or previous occurrence.

See the picture below at the end.

To search in a specific string, select that string and define the scope to ***Selected lines***. This behaves the same way as for mouse-selected text.

***Note:*** this screenshot has been taken from recent version of Eclipse on Mac computer. See the software details:

> Eclipse IDE for Java Developers
>   Version: 2019-12 (4.14.0)
>   Build id: 20191212-1212

Good luck

[image]

Comment: Thank you, my friend. This was exactly it.